# difficulty in adding dynamic checkboxes to dynamically added view

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have added three dynamic views to my activity, now i want to add dynamic checkboxes to one of them, but its giving me nullPointerException Error. This is xml layout of my view

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMod"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="What does this symptom occur or when is it worse?"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Checkbox_Layout3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >"

        </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the code for dynamic View

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
case R.id.mod:
        LinearLayout modLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout3);
        if(modLayout== null) {
             LinearLayout myLayout3 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
             View hiddenInfo3 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.taking_modalation, myLayout3, false);
             myLayout3.addView(hiddenInfo3);
        }

        LinearLayout checkboxLayout3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Checkbox_Layout3);
         for (int i = 0; i < data_mod.length; i++) {
                CheckBox cbmod = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
                cbmod.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                cbmod.setButtonDrawable(id);
                cbmod.setText(data_mod[i]);
                checkboxLayout3.addView(cbmod);
            }
        break;
    }
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong with the java code, thanks in advance.
edit:
This is logcat report

```
09-14 02:06:14.380: D/AndroidRuntime(1019): Shutting down VM
09-14 02:06:14.380: W/dalvikvm(1019): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a4eba8)
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019): Process: com.example.mydb, PID: 1019
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.example.mydb.DetailActivity.onClick(DetailActivity.java:198)
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-14 02:06:14.420: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The nullPointerException error happened at CheckboxLayout.addView(cb).

Comment: if you dont post the logcat output with the nullpointerexception and where does it happen people won't lose a couple hours trying to figure it out :)

Comment: Have added logcat :)

Comment: @rupps now will u please lose your couple of minutes to help me? :(

Comment: sure.. but is difficult to tell as you reference layouts that are unknown to me, like R.id.linearlayout2. And the names are a little messy. The problem is obviously checkboxLayout3 is null (as logcat apparently tells you). Try to change  `LinearLayout checkboxLayout3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Checkbox_Layout3);` for `LinearLayout checkboxLayout3 = (LinearLayout) modLayout.findViewById(R.id.Checkbox_Layout3);` , that is, find the view from the inflated view rather than from the root. From your code also when modlayout==null then assign it properly so modLayout.findViewById doesnt crash

Comment: @rupp, i figured out the solution, i was getting nullPointerException because data_mod was not properly initialized so checkboxLayout3 was empty :)

Comment: but now came across another problem :p as i have three buttons in my activity, and on clicking any of these i get the inflated view for that button, but now when i click the same button two times, i get the view for that button two times,can you tell that what check should i assign on it so that it show the view only one time?

Comment: don't understand very well what you're telling me, however, I think this can come in handy: You can assign an arbitrary value to any view using `view.setTag(value)`, so maybe the first time you create the checkboxes you can do `checkBoxLayout3.setTag(ALREADY_CREATED)`, and before creating them again, just check `checkBoxLayout3.getTag()!=ALREADY_CREATED` , where ALREADY_CREATED is a final String that you define in your class like `final String ALREADY_CREATED="already"`

Comment: problem solved! it was causing problem due to wrong parenthesis. Thanks a lot for your time and replies :)